# How can I run python codes in a WD mycloud?

Tags: python, nas

I have a python code that I wish to schedule to run on a daily basis within my WD mycloud PR4100 but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.
Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 0):

Check out crontab - this will run a command on a regular basis.

**NOTE:**
***You can break important system functions if you mess up crontab*** so be sure you're comfortable editing cron files. You can check cron language using a site like https://crontab.guru/.

If you run `crontab -l` as root it will list all of the current entries, and `crontab -e` allows you to edit.

Also, if you install a cron expression as root it will run as root, so be sure you know what the command will do.